# How to access environment variable values Python on Linux?

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to call environment variables from Python script but having issues figuring out syntax:

Here is my script:

```
import requests
import os

user = os.environ.get('api_user')
password = os.environ.get('api_pass')

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/xml',
}

response = requests.post('https://mysite.mydomain.com/bla/commands/command/command/id/54', headers=headers, auth=(os.environ['user',"password"]))
```

Any suggestions how to call variables from OS environment?

It works if I use just curl

```
curl -X GET "https://mysite.mydomain.com/bla/commands/command/command/id/54" \
    -H "user: ${user}" \
    -H "password: ${password}" \
```

But trying to figure this out in Python which I have no experience.

Comment: maybe I should have formatted my question differently:

currently I have following script which works, however I want to hide auth part from script and pull it from environment variables:

`
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/xml',
}

response = requests.post('https://mysite.mydomain.com/bla/commands/command/command/id/54', headers=headers, auth=('myusername', 'mypassword'))
`

Answer (score 1):

`os.environ` is a like dictionary; you can't index multiple keys like you have in your example: `(os.environ['user',"password"])`

You need to access dict keys individually like at the top part of your code:

```
user = os.environ.get('api_user')
password = os.environ.get('api_pass')
```

Then if auth requires a dict of user and password, you can pass:

```
response = requests.post('https://mysite.mydomain.com/bla/commands/command/command/id/54', headers=headers, auth={'user': user, 'password': password})
```